# Using PandasUDFs to Generate Session IDs in a Window Function

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

On Spark 2.4, I am aiming to leverage the below pandas UDF in conjunction with an unbounded, ordered window to compute session events.

```
def generate_session_ids(events):
    initialize = True
    duration = 5
    session_id = 0
    session_start = 0
    for current_value in events:
        try:
            if initialize:
                initialize = False
                session_start = current_value
            
            if current_value < session_start + duration:
                yield session_id
            else:
                session_id += 1
                session_start = current_value
                yield session_id
        finally:
            pass
```

A sample workflow looks like:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [(1, 1.0, 1.0), (1, 6.0, 2.0), (2, 1.0, 3.0), (2, 2.0, 7.0), (2, 8.0, 10.0)],
        ("id", "time", "v"),
)

generate_session_ids_udf = f.pandas_udf(
    generate_session_ids,
    returnType=LongType(),
    functionType=f.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG,
)
w = (
    Window.partitionBy("id")
    .orderBy("time")
    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
)
df.withColumn(
    "test", generate_session_ids_udf(df["time"]).over(w)
).show()
```

The goal would be to have the following output, so I can later perform aggregations on v at the id/session_id granularity:

```
 id|time|   v |session_id|
+---+----+----+----------+
|  1| 1.0| 1.0|         0|
|  1| 6.0| 2.0|         1| 
|  2| 1.0| 3.0|         0|
|  2| 2.0| 7.0|         0|
|  2| 8.0|10.0|         1|
+---+----+----+----------+
```

However, I am receiving the below error:

```
Could not convert <generator object generate_session_ids at 0x7f6d25f90430> with type generator: tried to convert to int64
```

This is due to the `PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG` expecting a `LongType`, rather than a generator. However, as `PandasUDFType.SCALAR_ITER` is not available in 2.4, I am unsure of how to set up a UDF to expect a generator return type.

Is there any way to implement a pandas window-UDF in Spark 2.4 that iterates over an input series while tracking some internal state?